# Missing files from Ajax control Toolkit manifest error?`

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, calendar, compiler-errors

Hello this is the first time I have used Ajax. I added ajax to my visual studio 2010 toolbox and pulled a calendar over my text box. When I run my site I get this error.

```
MissingManisfestResourceException
```

`Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.NET4.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.`

Now it says I am missing `ExtenderControlBase`, Where can I get that?

My code of my calendar:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBday" runat="server" 
            style="z-index: 1; left: 327px; top: 436px" Height="22px"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender
                ID="Birthday" runat="server"
            onclientdateselectionchanged="CheckDateEalier" TargetControlID="txtBday" 
            PopupButtonID="btnBirth" PopupPosition="TopRight" >
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnBirth" runat="server" 
            ImageUrl="~/images/calendaricon.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you forgot to reference the assembly at the top of your content file and need a script manager here is a working example hope it helps.

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TB" runat="server" />
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="C" runat="server" TargetControlID="TB">
</asp:CalendarExtender>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```